# Trying to compare a list of dates to current date, but it's just returning false

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a list of dates (import from database), and I want my application to display a message if any of the dates in the list are bigger or equal to the current date. I thought this could be done with .some.

```
data() {
  return {
    currentDate: moment().locale(this.$i18n.locale).format('L'),
    listOfDates: [],
  };
},

computed: {
  datesBiggerOrCurrentDate() {
    return this.listOfdDates.some(date => date.listOfDates)
  },
},
```

And the template:

```
  <div v-if="this.listOfDates.length > 0 && datesBiggerOrCurrentDate >= currentDate" class="alert alert-warning">
    <i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle text-danger mr-1"></i>
    <strong class="text-danger">Warning!</strong> {{ 'Some text' }}
  </div>
```

But nothing is returned. In the console the computed property just returns "false" What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you use "some" method in the right way? Your computed value is called "datesBiggerOrCurrentDate" and in a template you try to compare it to a currentDate, but this computed value is a boolean not a date because "some" method returns boolean value.

You can read about the "some" method here [Array.prototype.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

Instead using of "some" method you should use "filter" method and compare dates by built-in momentjs method - "isSameOrAfter"

**Your computed value should be something like this:**

```
datesBiggerOrCurrentDate() {
      return this.listOfDates.filter(date => moment(date).isSameOrAfter(this.currentDate));
    },
```

You can try it on codepen - https://codepen.io/AlekseiKrivo/pen/vYVWzzr